# Как сделать запрос select и правильно связать таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, inner

Все привет, я туплю и не могу сообразить как сделать следующее.
Предположим есть у нас:

- таблица людей(person) которая состоит из id_person,name,surname. Имеет следующее содержимое:

  (1,"Иван",'Иванов'),
  (2,"Петро","Петров"),
  (3,"Петро","Петров");
- таблица машин(auto) которая состоит из id_auto,name,number. Имеет следующее содержимое:

  (1,"ford",'A101MP'),
  (2,"nissan","A151AO"),
  (3,"lada","M199BD"),
  (4,"mazda",'A333CK'),
  (5,"ИЖ","H777CO"),
  (6,"ГАЗ","H888HH");
- Есть таблица которая содержит набор,человек-машина, ибо у одного человека может быть несколько машин. Назовем таблицу autoPerson, состоит из id, id_person, id_auto; имеет следующее содержимое:

  (1,1,6),
  (2,2,4),
  (3,2,5),
  (4,2,1),
  (5,3,2),
  (6,3,3);

Мне нужно сформировать запрос select который выводил бы список пользователь и перечисление машин которые ему принадлежат. Желаемый результат выглядит следующим образом:

```
(1,"Иван",'Иванов','6'),
(2,"Петро","Петров",'4,5,1'),
(3,"Петро","Петров",'2,3');
```

Как мне это сделать?
У меня было много попыток, вот некоторые из них:

```
select p.*,SUM(concat(ap.id_auto,',')) from person p inner join autoPerson ap on ap.id_person=p.id_person group by p.id_person; 
select p.*,concat(ap.id_auto,',') from person p inner join autoPerson ap on ap.id_person=p.id_person group by p.id_person;
```

Пробовал так же создать хранимую процедуру с курсором, но там результат - происходит несколько ответов, что не комильфо.
Я знаю это элементарно и типично и я раньше делал это, но сейчас вылетело из головы. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Это делается с помощью GROUP_CONCAT.

```
select p.*,GROUP_CONCAT(ap.id_auto) from person p inner join autoPerson ap on ap.id_person=p.id_person group by p.id_person;
```